# Yandex Maps Api - How can I change location the placemark?

Tags: yandex-maps

How can I change location placemark on Yandex maps?

I added placemark and need change to location with javascript.

I've tried:

```
var LatLng = [ 22.2222, 33.3333 ];
myPlacemark.setPosition(LatLng);
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/IPointGeometryAccess-docpage/?from=SO#method_detail__setCoordinates) the method name is `setCoordinates` and it's applied to the *geometry* of the placemark, so the following should work:

```
myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(LatLng)
```